# Process /etc/passwd file to list all users whose home folder is in /home

Tags: text-processing, awk, wildcards, passwd

I have an example /etc/passwd file like this:

```
tom:x:1000:1000:Work:/home/tom:/bin/bash
george:x:1000:1000:Work:/home/george:/bin/bash
bla:x:1000:1000:Work:/home/bla:/bin/bash
boo:x:1000:1000:Work:/home/boo:/bin/bash
bee:x:1000:1000:Work:/root/list:/bin/bash
```

I'm trying to list all users with a home folder in `/home/`.

I wrote

```
cat ~/Desktop/e.txt |awk -F ":" '{if ($6 ~/^/home/) print $1;}'
```

where e.txt is the text I copied here.

I understand there is a problem with the backslash which is an escape character, but how do I fix it so I can list them in one line of a command?

Comment: A general advice besides the answers (that are coming with just one second in between!): It almost never makes sense to `cat` and pipe to tools like `awk` or `sed` or the like, as they can be given the filename as an argument.

Comment: cat e.txt| grep home | cut -d ":" -f 1

Comment: As all users have a UID of 1000 things might be a little tricky.

Comment: It was just an example i generated it should work on any /etc/passwd list. basically if someone has his bash in /home somehow grep home won't return the correct users. that's why i used awk

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal `grep home e.txt | cut -d ":" -f 1`. Congratulations on your UUOC award. However, this is not a good solution. What if there is a service "homebackups" that runs under a separate user named after the daemon? That's a false positive.

Comment: just learn grep and you will never need to ask a question like this again.

Comment: @NieDzejkob, I don't understand, what is wrong with the solution (besides the UUOC)?  It seems to work well for OP's pasted example above, although I might make it unique with `grep home e.txt | cut -d ":" -f 1 | sort | uniq`

Comment: @user1717828 False positives: If the string "home" is in any field other than the home directory, it will still catch that, unlike the other, more proper solutions. How about a user "homebackup" with home in /var/backup? What about the user "joesfan" with the shell set to "/home/joe/bin/awesomesh"? These shouldn't be picked up, but this solution does.

Comment: @Philippos re "It almost never makes sense to cat and pipe to tools [that] can be given the filename as an argument" - I generally use `cat > tool` variant of such command lines because it can improve clarity by maintaining the left-to-right flow of the input-processing-output of the pipe chain. It *is* less efficient, but almost always minimally so. It also makes adding a progress bar where relevant & useful when running interactively very obvious (just replace `cat` with `pv` if that is installed).

Comment: Thank you for illustrating why I wrote "almost never" instead of just "never".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may escape forward slashes as shown below:

```
awk -F':' '$6~/^\/home\//{ print $1 }' ~/Desktop/e.txt
```

---

Another *trick* would be using complex field separator:

```
awk -F'[:/]' '$7=="home"{ print $1 }' ~/Desktop/e.txt
```

- `-F'[:/]'` - treat both `:` and `/` to be a field separator

Comment: I believe the comment field (immediately before the home directory) is allowed to contain a slash.

Answer (score 12):

You can use quotes instead of `/` for the regex, to avoid escaping the `/`:

```
awk -F: '$6 ~ "^/home/" {print $1}' ~/Desktop/e.txt
```

With `awk`, `{if (foo) ... }` can often be simplified to just `foo {...}`.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming `e.txt` is actually `/etc/passwd`, you should actually use `getent passwd` instead of parsing the file since user account information may be stored in multiple locations specified in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` such as LDAP.

```
getent passwd | awk -F ':' '$6 ~ "^/home"'
```

Note that the `print` statement is implied when the condition is true. That will print the whole line, though. This will print only the user name:

```
getent passwd | awk -F ':' '$6 ~ "^/home" {print $1}'
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternative for those of us who just don't like awk:

```
grep -E '^([^:]*:){5}/home/' ~/Desktop/e.txt | cut -d: -f1
```

Explanation:

- `grep -E` enables the use of a few extended regular expression features
- The expression `([^:]*:)` matches one column, including the following ':' separator
- `^([^:]*:){5}` matches the first five columns of each line
- `^([^:]*:){5}/home/` matches every line where the 6th column starts with '/home/'
- `cut -d: -f1` selects only the first column of its input, using `:` as column separator

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `index` for fixed string matching like `grep -F` and use the return value to ensure it matches start of string

```
$ awk -F: 'index($6,"/home/")==1{print $1}' ip.txt
tom
george
bla
boo
```

or if regex is needed, pass it as environment variable

```
$ r='^/home/' awk -F: '$6 ~ ENVIRON["r"]{print $1}' ip.txt
tom
george
bla
boo
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for variety

```
$ perl -F: -lane 'print $F[0] if m(/home/)' e.txt
tom
george
bla
boo
```

Explanation

```
-F:     use ":" as field separator  
-lane
    l   add newline line-ending to every print statement
    a   auto-split input lines into @F array
    n   apply expression line by line to named file (or STDIN)
    e   evaluate perl commands given on command line

print $F[0]   print (only) the first field of each line
if m(/home/)  but only if the line contains the text /home/
```

Variation if you want to be picky about where `/home/` is found

```
perl -F: -lane 'print $F[0] if $F[5] =~ m(^/home/)' e.txt
```